# How to make drag and drop action in JavaFX 2.2 with Swing?

Tags: javafx-2

I have a problem with drag and drop event on JFXPanel that on located JPanel. When i push drag message to DragBoard, javaFX part of application doesnt work anymore. I think its about swing event mechanizm but i am not sure. There is no problem with other events. It made me confused. Is there any solution to this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
public class MyScene extends Scene {

    public MyScene(VBox vBoxMainLayout) {
        super(vBoxMainLayout);

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setPrefSize(10000, 10000);
        hBox.setSpacing(40);

        Button buttonSource = new Button("Source");
        buttonSource.setMinSize(60, 30);

        buttonSource.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                Dragboard db = startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                String message = "Drag operatation is done";
                content.putString(message);
                db.setContent(content);
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        buttonSource.setOnDragDone(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {

                event.consume();
            }
        });

        TextArea textAreaTarget = new TextArea();
        textAreaTarget.setMinSize(200, 500);

        hBox.getChildren().add(buttonSource);
        hBox.getChildren().add(textAreaTarget);

        vBoxMainLayout.getChildren().add(hBox);
    }

}

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox vBoxMainLayout = new VBox();
        MyScene myScene = new MyScene(vBoxMainLayout);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JFXPanel arg0 = new JFXPanel();
        arg0.setScene(myScene);
        frame.getContentPane().add(arg0);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like a bug. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a known deadlock in JavaFX 2.1 and pushed to 2.2 (thats what i learned from oracle ) but i guess it stil not solved.